# Microsoft.Translator

Tags: .net

I have a huge text file in english which I have to convert to Hindi Or say any other language.

I am reading each line of the text file and converting the english strings to Hindi using http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate.

So far there are no issues and text is translated and displayed on the screen.

Now I want to save this converted text and re-use it. When I save and open the file say in Notepad I see only junk characters and If I now read this file and reverse it to English the chacters displayed on the screen are also junk and not english as expected.

Please help with some source code.

I am open to both .NET or JAVA.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problem with encoding. Try saving the file using UTF-8 encoding. 
In C# this would be

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create)) {
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            w.WriteLine(<your string in Hindi here>);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your translation with UTF-8 encoding:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(yourfilename, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8))
{    
    sw.WriteLine("your text...");     
}
```